# reading huge chunks of data from stream: Is there something like "stream.hasBytesAvailable"

Tags: node.js, networking, socket.io

I need to read huge chunks of data from a stream. The length of the data is not known before sending. There is no special "end-character" in the stream.
Problem: i get multiple data-events for the stream, and i do not know, when to start the processing of the data.

I know a pattern from other programming languages where i can find out, if there is data left in the TCP stream (e.g. iOS and objective-C, where i have something like "hasBytesAvailable" for NSInputStream-objects).

Does something similar exist in node.js? Or how do i solve the problem with node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the length of the data in advance, without an EOF character, and with a held-open socket, you'll have to make use of the data's structural properties, i.e. parse it on the fly. That of course presumes the data *has* known structural properties (e.g. defined video format); if not, either your problem is simply unsolvable or you've got an "XY problem" (you've prematurely defined a solution without completely defining the real problem).

Answer (score 0):

The methods you refer to don't do what you say they do. They only tell you how much data can be read *without blocking.* Not the same thing at all.

The only way to read to the end of a stream is to read to the end of the stream. You will get an EOS when it is finished.

There isn't actually such a thing as the 'length of the data' when it comes from a network stream: consider that the peer could keep writing data forever.

Comment: My understanding so far: i get an EOS when the client is closing the socket, right? Im my case, the client simply waits, and does not close the socket. So - what to do then?

Comment: @peace97 In that case you need an application protocol: a length word prefix, a self-describing protocol like XML or Object Serialization, an STX/ETX system with escaping for internal STXs and escapes, etc.